# Limit of sequence 4

Tags: limits

I have to examine limit of the sequence $a_1 = 7$, $a_{n+1} = \frac{2^n + n^{(10^{17})}}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{(n^2)} - \frac{1}{n}} \cdot a_n$. $\lim_{n \to \infty}{(1+\frac{1}{n})^{(n^2)} - \frac{1}{n}} = e^2$ so $\lim_{n \to \infty}{\frac{2^n + n^{(10^{17})}}{(1 + \frac{1}{n})^{(n^2)} - \frac{1}{n}}} = \infty$ so $\lim_{n \to \infty}{a_n} = \infty$. Am I right?

Answer (score 0):

Not really, because asymptotically it's equal to $\exp(n)$:

$$(1+1/n)^{n^2} = ((1+1/n)^n)^n \approx \exp(n).$$

However, the exponential function $2^n$ grows faster than any polynomial, so for large enough values of $n$ we have:

$$\frac{2^n + n^{10^{17}}}{e^n} \approx \left(\frac 2 e \right)^n,$$

which tends to $0$.